# Find the resultant of three forces acting along the diagonals of a cube.

Tags: vectors

Not sure how to solve this one:

A particle at the corner P of a cube is acted on by three forces each of magnitude F, acting along the three diagonals of the three adjacent faces of the cube which pass through P. Find the resultant force.

I have got so far:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could split the three vectors into their components? Define a coordinate system etc. Or, alternatively, you could just add up the three vectors (geometrically) in your imagination. What would the resulting vector look like? What would its length be?

Comment: Perhaps you can share how you obtained the result of $2F$ ? We could try to see if there is something to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think in terms of Cartesian coordinates, where the directions of the cube edges correspond to the coordinate axes.
From the picture, we see that all of the components are equal to $\frac{F}{\sqrt{2}}$. This makes sense, because $\left(\frac{F}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{F}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^2 = F^2$.

When the components are summed together, each of the $i,j$ and $k$ components appears exactly twice in the sum. Therefore, the sum is
$$
2\times \left(\frac{F}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\hat{i} + 2 \times  \left(\frac{F}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \hat{j} + 2\times \left(\frac{F}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \hat{k} = \sqrt{2}F (\hat{i} + \hat{j}  + \hat{k} )
$$
which has length
$$
\sqrt{2}F \times \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{6}F
$$

Comment: Why does $\hat i + \hat j + \hat k = \sqrt 3$?

Comment: It doesn't equal to $\sqrt{3}$, but rather the length of $\hat{i}+\hat{j}+\hat{k}$ is $\sqrt{3}$. It can be shown by the Pythagorean theorem:
$$
L^2 = |\hat{i}|^2 + |\hat{j}|^2 + |\hat{k}|^2 = 1^2+1
^2+1^2= 3 \Rightarrow L = \sqrt{3}
$$

Comment: What does L represent?

Comment: $L$ is the length of the vector $\hat{i}+\hat{j}+\hat{k}$.